# Bind parameters to the sql request inside a @Subselect annotation in Spring boot?

Tags: java, spring

I'm working on a project in which I need to pass parameters to the `@subselect` annotation of spring boot (which maps a request to an entity), like the following example:

```
@Entity
@Immutable
@Subselect("SELECT FROM Employe INNER JOIN Employe_adress ON Employe.id = Employe_adress.eid WHERE Employe_adress.aid=?x")
public class Employe {
...
}
```

I want to bind an external value to "x" variable. Thank you.

Edit: One method I find is adding a global variable, but "The value for annotation attribute must be a constant expression".

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with @FilterDef and @Filter: https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-dynamic-mapping#parameterized-filtering-with-filter

#### Defining the @Filter

To demonstrate how `@Filter` works, let's first add the following filter definition to the `Employee` entity:

```
@FilterDef(
    name = "incomeLevelFilter", 
    parameters = @ParamDef(name = "incomeLimit", type = "int")
)
@Filter(
    name = "incomeLevelFilter", 
    condition = "grossIncome > :incomeLimit"
)
public class Employee implements Serializable {
```

The `@FilterDef` annotation defines the filter name and a set of its parameters that will participate in the query. The type of the parameter is the name of one of the Hibernate types ([Type](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/type/Type.html), [UserType](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/usertype/UserType.html) or [CompositeUserType](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/usertype/CompositeUserType.html)), in our case, an *int*.

The `@FilterDef` annotation may be placed either on the type or on package level. Note that it does not specify the filter condition itself (although we could specify the `defaultCondition` parameter).

*This means that we can define the filter (its name and set of parameters) in one place and then define the conditions for the filter in multiple other places differently.*

This can be done with the `@Filter` annotation. In our case, we put it in the same class for simplicity. The syntax of the condition is a raw SQL with parameter names preceded by colons.